# Change of variable question for two variable integral question

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have an integral that looks like 
$$
\int_{\zeta_1, \zeta_2 \in I} e^{\gamma F(\zeta_1, \zeta_2)} d\zeta_1 d\zeta_2,
$$
where $I$ is some fixed interval. 
I want to apply the change of variable 
$t_1 = F(\zeta_1, \zeta_2)$ and $t_2 = \zeta_2$, and 
express it in terms of $t_1$ and $t_2$. 
I wasn't sure how to set up the Jacobian and I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thank you very much.

PS I am assuming $F$ is "nice" so that it works... I would also appreciate some explanation of what I require for $F$ so that this actually works.

Comment: The transformation matrices are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this change of variable to make sense, you need at least that there exists an inverse to the function
$$G_{\zeta_2}:\zeta_1\longrightarrow F(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)$$
for all $\zeta_2$.

Comment: I was wondering what is the Jacobian that I will be using in the end?

Comment: @JohnnyT. If you have such an inverse, then you can write down your change of variables and compute the Jacobian you need.